# How to set the cloud_roleName for Application Insights for .NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-application-insights

I am trying to set the cloud_RoleName property to disambiguate different components in a system tracked with Azure Application Insights.

How can I set the property for services running with ASP.NET Core?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

RoleNames are by default populated. Is that not the case you observe or you want to override the behaviour? To override the rolename, the following should help:

Write a TelemetryInitializer like the one below to populate RoleName to your desired value.

```
public class MyRoleNameInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer  
 {
      public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
        {
           telemetry.Context.Cloud.RoleName = "MyCustomRoleName";
        }
 }
```

Then add the following line to add the TelemetryInitializer to the configuration, in the `ConfigureServices` method of you application startup class.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, MyRoleNameInitializer>();
    }
```

Note: If you used `AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry()` in the `ConfigureServices` of your Startup class to add Application Insights, then the above line should be done *before* `AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry()` as shown below.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, MyRoleNameInitializer>();
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry("ikey");
    }
```

Comment: I'm using the `UseApplicationInsights` method to bootstrap application insights as part of the creating the IWebHost in the main startup method, before Startup is run. I'm never calling AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry ...

Comment: I see how I can do what you are suggesting by also calling ConfigureServices extension method on the IWebHostBuilder ... if you update your answer to also include that method I'll accept it.

Comment: You don't need to call both `UseApplicationInsights` and `AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry` - use only one. In your case since you are using `UseApplicationInsights`, then you just need to add this line in `ConfigureServices`                         
                                                         
                `services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, MyRoleNameInitializer>();`